# Extract day and registered date months in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to check if a day is holiday'm using the method below. The sql alone in SqliteExpert works but the error code `%d can not format arguments java.lang.String`

How can I fix?

```
public void checkFeriados(String diaMes,String data){
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DB(ctx).getReadableDatabase();
    String sqlFeriados = String.format("select * from feriados where strftime('%d-%m',data)='%s';", diaMes);
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery(sqlFeriados, null);

    if (rs.getCount() > 0){
        feriado=true;
    }else{
        feriado = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't use String.format to make sql queries. use selectArgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strftime arguments are being interpreted by java, not sqlite:

```
String sqlFeriados = [..snip..] strftime('%d-%m',data)='%s';", diaMes);
                                           ^---------------------^
```

You'll need to use `%%` to prevent Java from seeing them as .format() placeholders:

```
String sqlFeriados = [..snip..] strftime('%%d-%%m',data)='%s';", diaMes);
                                                          ^-------^
```

`%%` in a .format() is reduced to a single `%` in the formatted string.